# Cannot edit rails credentials Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am working on a Rails 5.2 app and I have installed and setup active_storage, however, I can't seem to edit or show the rails credentials.

Here is an output of the error

```
ben@ben-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/benbagley$ EDITOR="atom --wait" rails credentials:edit
Traceback (most recent call last):
    38: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    37: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    36: from /home/ben/Desktop/benbagley/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    35: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:70:in `require'
    34: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:70:in `require'
    33: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    32: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    31: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    30: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    29: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    28: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    27: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    26: from /home/ben/Desktop/benbagley/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    25: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
    24: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
    23: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
    22: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    21: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    20: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    19: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    18: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    17: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    16: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    15: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    14: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    13: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    12: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    11: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/credentials/credentials_command.rb:26:in `edit'
    10: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command/helpers/editor.rb:26:in `catch_editing_exceptions'
     9: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/credentials/credentials_command.rb:27:in `block in edit'
     8: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/credentials/credentials_command.rb:50:in `change_credentials_in_system_editor'
     7: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:54:in `change'
     6: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
     5: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:42:in `read'
     4: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:79:in `decrypt'
     3: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:21:in `decrypt_and_verify'
     2: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:157:in `decrypt_and_verify'
     1: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:183:in `_decrypt'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:206:in `rescue in _decrypt': ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage (ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage)
```

However, when I generate a new app I can edit and show the credentials. So not sure on the issue with this app as I haven't changed the master key.

EDIT::

I'm also getting

```
ben@ben-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/benbagley$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.0 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.11.4 (ruby 2.5.0-p0), codename: Love Song
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-20 14:39:37 +0100
   (5.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
  ↳ /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Processing by PagesController#welcome as HTML
  Rendering pages/welcome.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered pages/welcome.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1149ms (Views: 1136.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/works" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-20 14:39:41 +0100
Processing by WorksController#index as HTML
  Rendering works/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Work Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "works".* FROM "works"
  ↳ app/views/works/index.html.erb:5
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 2], ["record_type", "Work"], ["name", "header_image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/works/index.html.erb:7
  Rendered works/index.html.erb within layouts/application (63.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 71ms (ActiveRecord: 15.9ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage):
    4: 
    5:     <% @works.each do |work| %>
    6:     <section class="max-w-md w-full lg:flex mb-2 shadow-md">
    7:       <section class="h-48 lg:h-auto lg:w-64 flex-none bg-cover rounded-t lg:rounded-t-none lg:rounded-l text-center overflow-hidden" style="background-image: url('<%= polymorphic_url work.header_image %>'); background-position: 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;" title="<%= work.title %>">
    8:       </section>
    9:       <section class="border-r border-b border-l border-champagne-dark lg:border-l-0 lg:border-t bg-champagne-dark rounded-b lg:rounded-b-none lg:rounded-r p-4 flex flex-col justify-between leading-normal">
   10:         <section class="mb-6">

(erb):12:in `<main>'
app/views/works/index.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_works_index_html_erb__3122246537996604426_69953460278620'
app/views/works/index.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_works_index_html_erb__3122246537996604426_69953460278620'
^C- Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
=== puma shutdown: 2018-05-20 14:39:55 +0100 ===
- Goodbye!
Exiting
```

Answer (score 23):

Comment the lines where you use your credentials and run `EDITOR="atom --wait" rails credentials:edit` (and uncomment them after you edit it). If this doesn't work, delete credentials.yml.enc and try again.

Comment: remove credentials.yml.enc and master.key then rerun `rails credentials:edit` worked. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Move or remove credentials.yml.enc and master.key and rerun `rails credentials:edit`. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as well. I found out that running `EDITOR="atom --wait" rails credentials:edit` was not sufficient.

If you set `Rails.application.credentials.some_api_key` in your source code without first defining it in your encrypted credentials, you will be unable to edit the credentials file or even view it. This is presumably because the entire application must run in order for the credentials to be decrypted.

Comment: For me, I just had to remove instances of Rails.application.credentials from my application.rb file and then I was able to run the rails credentials:edit command. Thankfully it seems like you don't need to remove these from every file in the code.