# Edting rails credentials is failing on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cmd, credentials

I want to edit credentials.yml.enc in a rails project running on Windows but cannot seem to get the command to work as expected. The command for this is `EDITOR="vim --wait" rails credentials:edit.` Since am using Windows I tried `EDITOR="code --edit" rails credentials:edit` which gives an error ("The term 'EDITOR=code -wait' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"). I read on a blog where `export EDITOR="vim"` was used and I tried `SET EDITOR="code"` which didn't work. I have searched and checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50435193/cannot-edit-rails-credentials-rails-5-2)...failed as well. All I have tried has failed. Can this be done on windows? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
set EDITOR=notepad
rails credentials:edit
```